# is there a better way to structure this jquery for this accordian?

Tags: jquery, css, performance

I know you can use jquery accordion function to achieve this, but I was having a go at going it another way.

You can see the code I have put together here...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGvbF

Is there a better way of structuring the jquery?

```
$('.acchead').click(function(){
  //check if already open othwerwise...
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass("sel")){
    //remove the initially opened item
    if($(this).next().hasClass("init")){
      $(this).next().removeClass('init');
    }
   //close all items, remove any selected classes, open clicked item 
   $('.sel').slideUp();
   $('.acc .sel').removeClass('sel');
     $(this).next().slideDown().addClass('sel');
  }
});
```

Cheers

Comment: You better submit your question to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you could avoid to `div`-ify all elements. You may use headings, paragraph and sectional elements

Comment: and also you can define a variable named is_busy and with that you can determine that is there an active animating for your according then prevent the new animation from executing or put it in a line. That would make your according work better. You know if you click fast on some of headings you would not wait till the animations end.